# Requesta a random number serverside

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I am creating a turn based multiplayer game using google play services. The basic logic is like a boardgame where a player has to roll dices and get the amount of steps.

However im facing to a problem. Am i right that this number can't be created client-side because of cheating? If so, is there any possible way to request a random number from the api and sync that with other players?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The game creator generates a random seed which is used to initialize an instance of `java.util.Random(long seed)`.

This seed is then inserted into gamedata so the other clients can see it and initialize their own `Random`. Doing this, all clients will generate the same sequence of dice rolls and since `Random` implements `Serializable`, you can serialize it between runs of your program.

Inside your game data you will need to show what each player has done in some kind of circular buffer, so that each client has the chance to roll the dice and compare the results for itself and verify that no one is cheating.

---

But... I think that google play should take care of the security side of things, checking your executable's signature and blocking altered binaries, haven't looked into it, but it would make sense, no?

Regards.

Comment: Basically, in user3319531's opinion, using the same seed for both players will yield the same sequence of "random" rolls... I'm not sure if RNGs work this way.

Comment: From Javadoc:If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Comment: reading user3319531's anwser, this means i do not need to think about it at all, and just use a regular random number?

Comment: All clients must start with the same seed, which could be system.currentTimeMillis from the room creator and off you go! That's why they are called PSEUDO random generators.